# How to se the históric of “npm deprecate” command or the deprecated npm info

Tags: node.js, npm

After I execute this command:

```
npm deprecate "mini-tools"@"< 0.2.10" "dependencies are deprecated"
```

I don't know where see which is the info of deprecated versions (or the historic of `npm deprecate` executions) about this module.

I try

```
npm view mini-tools
```

I see a lot of info but not about deprecations

I also try `npm outdated` but is info of deprecated dependencies.

Where I can see which versions of one module are deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an on line way to view this information. In:

https://registry.npmjs.org/mini-tools

we have information for all versions in a big JSON. If a version is deprecated it haves a "deprecated" entry with the reason.

From: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10584/c%C3%B3mo-ver-el-hist%C3%B3rico-de-npm-deprecate/10729#10729